# Can A M21 Hollow Point ammo hunter eat his meat in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, food, meat, hunting

Situation
M21 (308.Winchester Semi-Auto) Hollow Point ammo
Deer
Headshot (Insta-Death)
Can a Muslim do that ? Would that be helal to eat ?

Comment: Did you say Bismillah when pulling the trigger?

Comment: When the hunter fires his gun, he has to say Bismillah. If that kills the deer instantly then it is halal for him to eat. But if he didn't say Bismillah then it is not halal for him to eat it. (And just FYI - if the deer isnt instantly killed, then you have to go and slaughter it as normal including saying Bismillah again).

Comment: At first sight i was asking myself what is this all about (M21 etc.). Just as an advice it would be helpful if you added any necessary information for the readers!

Comment: @uma I dont have an rifle as an 14 Y/O.......

Comment: @Medi1Saif That was the neccesary information , When you fire an 
FMJ bullet, It doesn't kill the deer instanly but passes through the body, But if you use Hollow Point ammo, Head goes "Splat" And by "Splat" I am not joking, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfPynXygox0